# How can i replace the woocommerce cart table with custom html

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to replace the woocommerce cart page table element that displays the item name, price, quantitiy, etc. With my own HTML. I had a look at the hooks woocommerce and wordpress provide but with no luck from this website: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-cart-page/. Everything i tried does not remove the table element.

```
<form class="woocommerce-cart-form" action="https://test.com/zakljucek-nakupa/" method="post">
 <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart woocommerce-cart-form__contents"></table>
</form>
```

I want to essnetially replace the table inside that form with my own html. Is this even possible with hooks?

Comment: There are two hooks before and after that table, https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php#L23 - but the table gets output directly, so the only way to remove it, would be to use output buffering; and I am not too sure if works well to try and enable that with one hook, and then disable it again with the next one. If you want to make rather major changes, that can't be achieved in a reasonable way by using hooks - then this would really rather be a case where you should overwrite the template file in your own theme.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, i completely forgot about templates. Thank you i will follow this.

Comment: @Cbroe Could you post this as an answer so i can mark the question as resolved please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two hooks before and after that table, https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php#L23 - but the table gets output directly, so the only way to remove it, would be to use output buffering; and I am not too sure if works well to try and enable that with one hook, and then disable it again with the next one.

If you want to make rather major changes, that can't be achieved in a reasonable way by using hooks - then this would really rather be a case where you should overwrite the template file in your own theme.